# a better alternative for "computerize"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a better alternative for **"computerize"**? Although the word is used in many writings, it doesn't sound good to me. I don't like it. **For the context**: consider a psychological test (e.g., an IQ test) that was used to be administered manually, is going to be **computerized** so that it could run on personal computers.

Comment: Do you mean to put something written or sounded into a digital format ("digitize")? Or to write an algorithm to have a computer solve a task in the same way that a person does?

Comment: @rajah9 If OP is seeking a word with your latter sense (the algorithmic one), I'd suggest *automate*.

Comment: Great suggestion, @DanBron.

Comment: The term "computerize" could be taken to mean many different things, up to and including "turn into a computer". :) We should be asking our guest @EhsanAbd for more information instead of making assumptions. Ehsan, can you elaborate on the context of "computerized" that is most relevant to your question?

Comment: Well, I've used "computerears" a few times.  (But "computermouth" just doesn't have the right connotation.)

Comment: @rajah9, @R Mac, context added, sorry that I took it for granted.

Comment: By the way I prefer __computerize__ over __automate__.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/computerized

Comment: Automate, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Although there is not a perfect solution to a problem of specificity ("computerize" is probably the modern word you want but are justifiably hesitant to use), I suggest the use of the word "program".  While it may itself be mildly ambiguous, it should satisfy in context.

> I hate that we waste all this paper for this assessment, especially when we have to enter the data into a computer later.  Can't we program the test?

Answer (score 1):

A good analogy for the OP's psychometric test may be the GRE.

The Graduate Record Examination (GRE) has both tests that use a number 2 pencil and that use a keyboard and mouse.

They call the former a [Paper-delivered test](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/register/paper/). They call the latter a *computer-delivered test*. The ETS site does not have any information on when the computer-delivered test was first administered to students, nor what they called the process of *creating* / *programming* / *computerizing* said test.

This sounds tinny to my ear, but let's soldier on.

I suppose one could say: *create a computer-delivered test.*

A programmer might *program* or *implement* a computer-based test.

Answer (score 1):

Since a test like this cannot be considered to be exactly the same thing if administered in different forms, I would consider this to be a new **version** of the test, which is appropriate as it is a piece of software. Along with this, you can point out the important difference in the new version, which is that it is for a personal computer, commonly abbreviated as "PC".

> This has traditionally been a paper test, but will soon be
>   released in a PC version.

Answer (score 0):

"Consider a psychological test (e.g., an IQ test) that was used to be administered manually, is going to be ***[reformatted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reformat#Verb)*** to run on personal computers and other devices."

Another suggestion: "is going to be ***adapted*** for deployment on personal computers and other devices."